# Recursive static enum and singleton definitions

Tags: java, enums, static, singleton, classloader

TL;DR: Don't do what I did.  Run and read the code comments in the minimum reproducer below.

I have an `enum` that takes an instance of a `class` which itself is a singleton that takes a value from the `enum`.  Just reading that suggests that this is a bad design.

Below we can see some inconsistent results; e.g., printing `MyEnum.VALUE.myClassInstance` before calling `MyClass.getInstance()` results in `MyEnum.VALUE.myClassInstance` being non-`null`, but calling `MyClass.getInstance()` before printing `MyEnum.VALUE.myClassInstance` results in `MyEnum.VALUE.myClassInstance` being null.

But why??

```java
public class StrangeEnumFailure {
    
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // Enabling any of the following three lines will cause the prints to print the expected values
        
        // MyEnum.VALUE.getMyClassInstance();
        // MyEnum.VALUE.getClass();
        // System.out.println(MyEnum.VALUE.myClassInstance); // Not null!
        
        System.out.println(MyClass.getInstance());             // Not null
        System.out.println(MyEnum.VALUE.myClassInstance);      // null... but only if we do it after MyClass.getInstance()!
        System.out.println(MyClass.INSTANCE);                  // Not null
        System.out.println(MyEnum.VALUE.getMyClassInstance()); // null
        System.out.println(MyEnum.VALUE.myClassInstance);      // null
    }
    
    public static class MyClass {
        
        static final MyClass INSTANCE = new MyClass(MyEnum.VALUE);
        
        final MyEnum enumValue;
        
        private MyClass(final MyEnum enumValue) {
            this.enumValue = enumValue;
        }
        
        static MyClass getInstance() {
            return INSTANCE;
        }
    }
    
    public enum MyEnum {
        VALUE(MyClass.INSTANCE);
        
        final MyClass myClassInstance;
        
        MyEnum(final MyClass myClassInstance) {
            this.myClassInstance = myClassInstance;
        }
        
        MyClass getMyClassInstance() {
            return this.myClassInstance;
        }
    }
}
```

(don't judge the code, the non-private fields and lack of JavaDoc are for ease of demo purposes only)

Java version info:

```
openjdk 17.0.3 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.3+7 (build 17.0.3+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.3+7 (build 17.0.3+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 0):

The construction results in the class-loading being order dependent (gross).

If you ask Java to use `MyClass` first:

- load `MyClass`

  - set `INSTANCE`

    - load `MyEnum`

      - get `MyClass.INSTANCE`
      - `MyClass.INSTANCE == null`, as it hasn't been set yet because we're literally in the process of setting it, so
      - set `this.myClassInstance = null`
    - set `this.enumValue = MyEnum.VALUE`

Thus, `INSTANCE` is *not* `null` at the end of this load sequence, but it *was* `null` when we grabbed it when we were instantiating the `enum` value.

On the other hand, if you ask Java to use `MyEnum` first:

- load `MyEnum`

  - get `MyClass.INSTANCE`

    - load `MyClass`

      - set `INSTANCE`

        - get `MyEnum.VALUE`, which we're currently instantiating
        - set `this.myEnumValue = MyEnum.VALUE`
      - `INSTANCE` is now non-`null`
  - set `this.myClassInstance = MyClass.INSTANCE` where `MyClass.INSTANCE != null` because we just constructed it when loading `MyClass`

And, thus, everything is set-up as expected.

I did this by accident and am going to be reverting it because it is obviously a bad design choice.

Don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a *[singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)* would not be required, in *Java*.

Although, after some research, it appears that an *enum* should be used, over a class.
Considering that it is inherently, a single instance.

```java
enum MyClass {
    instance;

    String s;

    static MyClass getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    String getS() {
        return s;
    }

    void setS(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Objects.toIdentityString(this);
    }
}

enum MyEnum {
    VALUE(MyClass.instance);

    final MyClass myClassInstance;

    MyEnum(final MyClass myClassInstance) {
        this.myClassInstance = myClassInstance;
    }

    MyClass getMyClassInstance() {
        return this.myClassInstance;
    }
}
```